# Copy blobs from one Azure container to another using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC with C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, azure-container-instances

I have one blobs container which is private, my files are uploaded successfully.

Now, if I copy and paste file url, then it throws "File Not Found" error because It is in private container.

So I want a public url of file.. for this I created a separate public container.

Now I want to copy files/blob from private container to public container and generate a public url. So that I can use that public url.
I also want to delete  that file/blob from public container after 1 hour.

Please help on this.

I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that.  To generate a public URI for a blob in a private container, simply [generate a SAS URI for the blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=dotnet#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob) with an expiration and read-only permissions.